# making a view from sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view

I have two tables:

```
1. Products with the following columns:
* ID
* SerialNumber
* Name
2. ProductsData
* ID
* ProductID
* DateOfData
* DataValue
```

I want to get a view with the following:

```
* Product name.
* product serial number
* the last date of data for this product.
* the data value in this datetime
```

How do I do it through SQL query to make a view ?

Thanks

Comment: I tried something with innerjoin but it returned all the rows in the second table. I want only the last data

Comment: @user1902346 Next time, post your attempts along with your question so people will know you put some effort in this before asking. This generally leads to a more answers and fewer downvotes on your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW vw_SomeName
AS
SELECT P.Name, P.SerialNumber, PD.DataValue, MAX(PD.DateOfData)
FROM Products P INNER JOIN ProductsData PD
ON P.ID = PD.ProductID
GROUP BY P.Name, P.SerialNumber, PD.DataValue
```

OR you can try this aswell

```
    CREATE VIEW vw_SomeName
    AS
    SELECT P.Name, P.SerialNumber, PD.DataValue, LastDate
    FROM Products P 
                    CROSS APPLY (
                                SELECT TOP 1  PD.DataValue, MAX(PD.DateOfData) AS LastDate
                                FROM ProductsData PD
                                WHERE P.ID = PD.ProductID
                                GROUP BY PD.DataValue
                                ORDER BY LastDate DESC
                                ) PD
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get also the DataValue in that date ?

Comment: I have edited the code have a look please :)

Comment: Thanks but the second is syntax error and the first returns to mee all the rows with the dates in the productsdata

Comment: Sorry when your not on sql server and only making queries in you head its a bit difficult to picture the whole query in your head :)
Have a look now I have edited it hopefully it should be working all good now.

Comment: It works. Great. I have another question if that's possible :) : I want to write in the product line the avarage of the values in the last 24 hours (another column). Is there a way doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Name, SerialNumber, ABB3.last_date, ABB3.DataValue 
FROM Products AS ABB4
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT ABB2.ProductID, last_date, DataValue
        FROM ProductsData AS ABB2
            LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT ProductID, MAX(DateOfData) AS last_date
            FROM ProductsData
            GROUP BY ProductID) AS ABB1 ON ABB1.ProductID = ABB2.ProductID 
            AND ABB1.last_date = ABB2.DateOfData)
        AS ABB3 ON ABB3.ProductId = ABB4.ID
```